# Using a trademarked item in another product

Tags: trademark

There is a trademarked product used in therapy that is used to increase breathing capacity. I would like to use that product in a kit with protocols and instructions that would improve its current use and expand its uses. How do I do that without infringing on the trademark or being limited by the trademark owners?

Answer (score 2):

You can onsell and repackage products, including products subject to trademarks and patents. Simply identify the original trademark within your package.

For example: [Oreo<sup>TM</sup> Cookie McFlurry<sup>TM</sup>](https://mcdonalds.com.au/menu/oreo-cookie-mcflurry). Oreo is TM Mondelēz International, McFlurry is TM McDonalds.